# Custom UITableViewCell not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a `UITableViewController` with a custom cell view. I created an empty Interface Builder document, then added a Table View Cell, then added a label to it. The Table View Cell has a corresponding class that extends `UITableViewCell`. The Table View Cell's label in Interface Builder is linked (outet) to the var in my custom class

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel!
```

The problem is that the the custom cell never renders, it's always  blank (I tried the background color trick too). I never see the label. In fact the label is always null.

In my `UITableViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`, I've tried

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyTableCellView", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

as well as

```
tableView.registerClass(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

I also have

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    print("cellForRowAtIndexPath, cell = \(cell), someLabel = \(cell.someLabel)")
    return cell
}
```

At runtime it is dequeueing as `cell` is non-null, however `cell.someLabel` is nil.

What does it take to have a custom table view cell render?

Comment: Same problem here, I can click the cell but it does not render. Did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

someLabel has no value. Try:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.someLabel.text = "Put label text here"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this way. I load the xib file within the custom table view cell class.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        cell = loadViewFromNib()
        cell.frame = self.bounds
        cell.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(cell)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UITableViewCell {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)
        let cell = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UITableViewCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

Along with:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    print("cellForRowAtIndexPath, cell = \(cell), someLabel = \(cell.someLabel)")
    return cell
}
```

One other thing to do is to set the **File's Owner** in MyTableViewCell.xib file to MyTableViewCell class.